# Probability of collinearity (circles)

Tags: probability

I have question for you guys I made. It's simple to understand but not easy to solve (I believe). I haven't solved it, and don't really know how to approach it or reach to the solution. So hopefully someone in here with a lot more mathematical knowledge can solve it.

Anyways.. here it is:

You have a circle of radius R.
You also have 3 small circles with radius R/10.

**Question:**

If these smaller circles are placed inside the large circle, *randomly*, what is the probability that their centres are collinear? (In other words, you can draw a **straight** line that connects the centres of the three circles)

**Restrictions**

- The smaller circles can be at most tangent to each other (never overlap).
- The smaller circles can be at most tangent to the larger circle (never outside)

Comment: The probability is $0$ I believe.

Comment: Surely it can't be 0? Close to maybe, but I don't think it will be 0. Can you explain why?

Comment: 0.0000000000000........

Comment: Yes, maybe the answer is interesting, but if I changed the question a little bit, the probability would be much higher. But don't know how to approach it anyways.

Comment: Perhaps it can be viewed this way: Take circles 1 and 2 and connect their centres with a vector. Then consider the same with circles 1 and 3. Now, what is the angle between these two vectors? We know that it can be a real number, and we want this angle to be zero. So if we choose a real number at random, from the interval $0 \ldots \pi$, what is the probability that the result is exactly zero (or $\pi$, why not ...) ? It's pretty clear that the **measure** of this set is zero, therefore the probability is essentially zero.